# Pandas: Check if one date column falls between two date columns, if true populates output

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame with 3 date fields `purchaseDate`, `releaseDate`, and `ceaseDate`. An sample of the dataframe is seen below.

```
Product purchaseDate    releaseDate ceaseDate
ABC    20/12/2020       01/01/2021  02/01/2022
ZXC    15/01/2021       05/01/2021  02/01/2022
QWE    29/03/2021       06/01/2021  02/01/2022
ASD    13/04/2021       07/01/2021  02/01/2022
```

If the `purchaseDate` falls between `releaseDate`, and `ceaseDate` output of `Active` should be populated in a new column `Status`. If it `purchaseDate` falls outside these two dates it should show as `Inactive`. The required output is seen below.

```
Product purchaseDate    releaseDate ceaseDate   status
ABC     20/12/2020      01/01/2021  02/01/2022  Inactive
ZXC     04/01/2021      05/01/2021  02/01/2022  Inactive
QWE     29/03/2021      06/01/2021  02/01/2022  Active
ASD     13/04/2021      07/01/2021  02/01/2022  Active
```

Any assistance that could be provided would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: for the given dataframe all are inactive...so why you put active in last 2 rows?

Comment: i think second one should be *Active* rest is true.

Comment: Yes. The second should be active @MustafaAydın

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert date columns to `datetime` type and use `between` function

```
date_columns = df.filter(regex='Date').columns
df[date_columns] = df[date_columns].apply(pd.to_datetime, format='%d/%m/%Y')
```

Use `np.where` to insert value according to the condition

```
in_between = df.purchaseDate.between(df.releaseDate, df.ceaseDate)
df['status'] = np.where(in_between, 'Active', 'Inactive')
print(df)
```

Output

```
  Product purchaseDate releaseDate  ceaseDate    status
0     ABC   2020-12-20  2021-01-01 2022-01-02  Inactive
1     ZXC   2021-01-15  2021-01-05 2022-01-02    Active
2     QWE   2021-03-29  2021-01-06 2022-01-02    Active
3     ASD   2021-04-13  2021-01-07 2022-01-02    Active
```

NOTE: Don't forget to `import numpy as np`

Answer (score 1):

Convert to datetime:

```
df = (df.assign(**df.filter(like='Date')
        .transform(pd.to_datetime, format="%d/%m/%Y"))
      )

  Product purchaseDate releaseDate  ceaseDate
0     ABC   2020-12-20  2021-01-01 2022-01-02
1     ZXC   2021-01-15  2021-01-05 2022-01-02
2     QWE   2021-03-29  2021-01-06 2022-01-02
3     ASD   2021-04-13  2021-01-07 2022-01-02
```

Use the `between` function and map the boolean output to active and inactive:

```
(df.assign(status = df.purchaseDate.between(df.releaseDate, df.ceaseDate)
   .map({True:"Active", False:"Inactive"}))
 )

  Product purchaseDate releaseDate  ceaseDate    status
0     ABC   2020-12-20  2021-01-01 2022-01-02  Inactive
1     ZXC   2021-01-15  2021-01-05 2022-01-02    Active
2     QWE   2021-03-29  2021-01-06 2022-01-02    Active
3     ASD   2021-04-13  2021-01-07 2022-01-02    Active
```